# PHP shell_exec command doesn't work

Tags: php, linux, bash, lamp

I am trying learn to execute shell scripts from within PHP code. So, I made a test program to execute a bash script from within PHP. However, it has no effect. The relevant code is shown below.

```
<?php 
.......
shell_exec('/bin/bash /var/www/html/just_touch.sh');
?>
```

The `just_touch.sh` script just creates a new file, like as shown below.

```
touch /home/user/some.txt
```

I was expecting to have file `/home/user/some.txt` after execution, but no, it isn't made. What mistake, am I doing?

**P.S:** The following code works though.

```
$output = shell_exec('ls /home/user');
echo $output;
```

Does this have anything to do with permissions?

Moreover, I notice that while this prints "Can you see me?".

```
$output = shell_exec('echo Can you see me?');
echo $output;
```

This doesn't!

```
shell_exec('echo Can you see me?')
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Give the full path to your /somedir/just_touch.sh

Comment: It still doesn't work. Is there a way to see what error occurs from Mozilla?

Comment: To see something in Mozilla use `passthru()` instead of `shell_exec()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Comment: Most likelely `/home/user/some.txt`is not writable by webservers *userid*

Comment: How can I make that writable then? How can I even check if its writable or not through webservers userid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Stderr* is lost when using `shell_exec`. You might wan't to use:

```php
shell_exec('/bin/bash /var/www/html/just_touch.sh 2>&1');
```

Comment: Very useful indeed, because now I see the message, touch: cannot touch '/home/user/some.txt': Permission denied. These permission rights are killing me though :(! Do, you know anyway to solve these permission rights?

Comment: Make the target directory `/home/user` writable by the webserver user. I.e make it group-writable: `chmod g+w /home/user` and  set the group of the home directory to the same group the webserver is running: `chgrp wwwrun /home/user`

Comment: I see. At the moment I got away by setting permissions to 777. But I think that would be very insecure. I'll checkout with your approach.